# NERDTree jump to tab number

Tags: vim, tabs, nerdtree

In NERDTree, if I'm at the 5th tab, switching to the 2nd tab would require at minimum two tab shifts (assuming the 5th tab were the last one).

Is there any way to switch to the nth tab like Chrome or Firefox does with Ctrl+2 (such as with 2)?

Comment: Tab switching has *nothing* to do with nerdtree. Don't let plugins override your vim experience.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if NERDTree has a different notion of tabs than vim, but in vim you can switch to tab number 2 with `2gt`. (See `:h gt|144`).

Comment: Is there a way to go to the last tab? 0gT just moves back one tab and 1329475gt doesn't do anything but ring a bell.

Comment: There's the `:tablast` command. You can map something to it.